# Как будет выглядеть .bat файл для Windows?

Tags: java, cmd

Всем привет.
Есть код для запуска программы на Linux в файле run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
javac -sourcepath src -classpath lib/stdlib.jar -d out src/game/Run.java
java -classpath out:lib/stdlib.jar game.Run
```

Вопрос, как будет выглядеть .bat файл для запуска данной программы на Windows?

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off

javac -sourcepath src -classpath lib\stdlib.jar -d out src\game\Run.java
java -classpath out;lib\stdlib.jar game.Run
```

Но объединять компиляцию и запуск - это плохая идея.